# R: Align hjust with points using two separate variables

Tags: r

I am able to align my first geom_text function with the points very easily. As I try to run the second variable on another geom_text function, it does not align with my points. How can I fix this?

```
    #library(devtools)
    #devtools::install_github("camdenk/mlbplotR")
    #library(ggplot2)
    Top10 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=xba.x, y=1:10)) +
    mlbplotR::geom_mlb_headshots(aes(player_id = player_id, x 
    = xba.x + 0.006), height = 0.12)+
    geom_point(colour = "black") + 
    geom_segment( aes(x=xba.y, xend=xba.x, y= 1:10, yend 
    =1:10))+
    theme_classic()+
    geom_point(aes(x=xba.x, y=1:10))+
    geom_point(aes(x=xba.y, y=1:10))+
    geom_text(aes(label = xba.y), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0)+
    geom_text(aes(label = xba.x), vjust = -0.55, hjust = 10, 
    size = 3.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Where is Top10 from?

Comment: Does this help: `geom_text(aes(x=xba.y, label = xba.y), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0)+
  geom_text(aes(x=xba.x, label = xba.x), vjust = -0.55, hjust = 10, 
            size = 3.0)`?

Comment: That unfortunately did not help. Still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Riley, you are sort of intermixing the data-structure for all your layers (I assume).
`ggplot2` uses inheritance between the layers. Thus be sure to understand how the x- and y-positions "loaded" in the "top-layer", i.e. `ggplot(aes(x=xba.x, y=1:10), influence your other layers.

Moreover, I recommend to work with a data frame and use this one consistently across all your layers. Note you are mixing references to the data frame Top10 and then set values directly (i.e. y = 1:10). Be sure about this ... and what it means.

When you run in troubles, I recommend to only assign or pipe your data object into the top-layer, i.e. `ggplot()`.
Then assign all aesthetics in all layers. Once you have what you are looking for, think about which aesthetics can be pushed upwards into the top-layer.

Notice that the labels of your plot all over the place? I.e. they do not consist with your x-axis. Thus, I am also not sure that you plotted your first `geom_text()` the way you want it (x values sort of consistent with x-axis). This signals already that the x-position is taken from "somewhere else".

```
# simulate your data - simplified
df <- tibble(xba.x = c(0.283, 0.253), xba.y = c(0.212,0.205), y = c(1,2) )

df
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  xba.x xba.y     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.283 0.212     1
2 0.253 0.205     2
```

Note: you can assign the ranking on your y-axis to the dataframe. Then you work on a consistent data object.

Now plot your point and associated labels:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
     geom_point(aes(x = xba.x, y = y), color = "red") +
     geom_point(aes(x = xba.y, y = y), color = "blue") +
     geom_text( aes(x = xba.x, y = y, label = xba.x), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0) +
     geom_text( aes(x = xba.y, y = y, label = xba.y), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0)
```

You will see the label values coincide (just above) your dots, and consistent with the x-axis.

Next try to understand how you "displace" the label horizontally with `hjust`. I took an arbitrary value.
You can "beautify" this to your liking

```
df %>%               # same as ggplot(data = df) <- your top level data object
ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = xba.x, y = y), color = "red") +
    geom_point(aes(x = xba.y, y = y), color = "blue") +
  #-------- let's keep the labels from above -----------------------------
    geom_text( aes(x = xba.x, y = y, label = xba.x), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0) +
    geom_text( aes(x = xba.y, y = y, label = xba.y), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0) +
  #-------- let's place them aside horizontally
    geom_text( aes(x = xba.x, y = y, label = xba.x), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0, hjust = -0.8) +
    geom_text( aes(x = xba.y, y = y, label = xba.y), vjust = -0.55, size = 3.0, hjust =  2) +
  #--------------------------------------------------
     xlim(0,1)    # this is only to limit the plot
```

You will now see the labels displaced (next to the original labels).
Have a look at the positioning, i.e. `aes(...)`. As you did not provide x- and y-asthesitcs, the `geom_text()`layers used the x- and y- supplied to the top-layer. Understanding inheritance in ggplot should help you to navigate complex set ups like yours (or if you work with multiple data objects).

[image]